# i am making a search but when printing why does the second input also come in

Tags: python, list

The code I am using is as follow:

```py
elif (menu == 4):
        cari = input("Masukan Data Mahasiswa Yang Akan Dicari : ")
        for mhs in data_semua_mhs:
            if (mhs["nim"]==cari):
                print('Nim : ',mhs['nim'])
                print('Nama : ',mhs['nama'])
                print('Gender : ',mhs['gender'])
                print('Ipk : ',mhs['ipk'])
            elif (mhs["nim"]!=cari):
                print("Data Tidak Tersedia")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOiVi.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "why does the second input also come in"? Do you mean why `print` prints both inputs passed to it, or are you having a problem with your code printing more than it should?

Comment: I tried to print only 1 item but item 2 also printed how to prevent item 2 from printing,You can see the picture I input 2 items in dictionaries and when I search for the first item else on the second item appears in print

Answer (score 0):

So you want to print "Data Tidak Tersedia" (data not available) if no student record is found, but you current system is the following: go through every student in the list. If it matches the id, print the data. If it does not match, print that the data is not available. However, this will print this for every student that does not match.

The following will print it only if no students match:

```
elif (menu == 4):
        cari = input("Masukan Data Mahasiswa Yang Akan Dicari : ")
        ada = False
        for mhs in data_semua_mhs:
            if (mhs["nim"]==cari):
                ada = True
                print('Nim : ',mhs['nim'])
                print('Nama : ',mhs['nama'])
                print('Gender : ',mhs['gender'])
                print('Ipk : ',mhs['ipk'])
        if ada is False:
            print("Data Tidak Tersedia")
```